# row wise distance calculation

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in r

```
  count1      count2      count3    Count4
    0           12          11        0
    12          0           44        23
    22          32          0         12
```

Formula that I want to apply on row wise is like this

```
  1st row     sqrt((count2-count3)^2)
  2nd row     sqrt((count1-count3)^2 + (count1-count4)^2 + (count3-count4)^2)
  3rd row     sqrt((count1-count2)^2 + (count1-count4)^2 + (count2-count4)^2)
```

I do not want to take columns with zero values into consideration. I have 6 columns like above. How can I do it in r?

Applying for loop and checking for every row for non zero elements is tedious task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  y <- x[x!=0]
  yc <- combn(y,2)
  sqrt(sum(apply(yc, 2, function(x) (x[1] - x[2])^2)))
})
```

gives:

> ```
> [1]   1.00000  39.82462  24.49490 776.72389
> ```

You can shorten this to:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  sqrt(sum(apply(combn(x[x!=0],2), 2, function(x) (x[1] - x[2])^2)))
})
```

In response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870113/row-wise-distance-calculation#comment76719744_44870284):

```
out <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  y <- x[x!=0]
  yc <- combn(y,2)
  sqrt(sum(apply(yc, 2, function(x) (x[1] - x[2])^2)))
})

100*out/max(out)
```

gives:

> ```
> [1]   0.1287459   5.1272551   3.1536171 100.0000000
> ```

---

Used data:

```
df <- structure(list(count1 = c(0L, 12L, 22L, 160L), count2 = c(12L, 0L, 32L, 621L), 
                     count3 = c(11L, 44L, 0L, 573L), count4 = c(0L, 23L, 12L, 624L)), 
                .Names = c("count1", "count2", "count3", "count4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

which looks like:

> ```
> > df
>   count1 count2 count3 count4
> 1      0     12     11      0
> 2     12      0     44     23
> 3     22     32      0     12
> 4    160    621    573    624
> ```

Comment: What if I have 6 columns? What do I have to change in the formula?

Comment: @Neil nothing needs to be changed, this works for 6 columns as well because you apply the function to very row

Comment: suppose numbers are `(160,621,573,624)` formula is `sqrt((160 - 621)^2 +  (160-573)^2
      + (160 - 624)^2 + (621 - 573)^2 + (621-624)^2 + 
        (573 - 624)^2 )`  according to your code its coming 1190,actual is 776

Comment: @Neil added those values as an extra row to the example data; the code is giving the correct output; see the update

Comment: `sqrt(sum(apply(combn(c(160,621,573,624), 2), 2, function(x) (x[1] - x[2])^2)))` gives `776.7239` as a result

Comment: Got it. Thanks a ton. Just a one question. Is there any way we can standardise these distances on the scale of `0-100` ? I am getting distances as `670,1234,567.. minimum is 2 and max is 2000`

Comment: @Neil divide everything from the outcome vector by the maximum and multiply with 100; see also the update, HTH